# Can I connect existing USB mouse and keyboard and VGA monitor to my Nexus 6

Tags: external-keyboard, external-display, mouse, android-pc, android-mini-pc

I guess question title sums it all. I have USB mouse, keyboard and VGA monitor. I am ready to buy couple of new adapters/cables. Will it be possible to connect all things up to my Nexus 6. I was thinking to do following:

- Buy Micro USB to USB 3.0 Hub something like [this](https://www.flipkart.com/mobilegear-usb-otg-adapter/p/itmegq5mgnsnvpzs)
- Buy USB 3.0 to VGA cable something like [this](http://www.amazon.in/TECHNOTECH-3-0-Multi-display-Converter-Resolution/dp/B014ZXCMVC/)
- Connect Hub to phone
- Connect mouse and keyboard to hub
- Connect USB3.0-to-VGA cable to hub
- Connect monitor to USB3.0-to-VGA cable

Will this even work?

Comment: Mouse and keyboard will probably work. I'm not sure about the monitor, though; I'm pretty sure there is no support for external monitors anyways.

Comment: any other way to connect VGA monitor to android with minimal hardware/software?

Comment: @Mahesha999 If your device has an HDMI port, yes you can connect a monitor.

Comment: My device? Which device? Do you mean if my monitor comes with HDMI male? Well my monitor has VGA male wire. And recently I bought HDMI male to VGA female adapter to plug in monitor to my HDMI-out only laptop... Will it work, if I buy USB-3 to HDMI female adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plug-and-play USB keyboard and mouse should work fine with your phone.

The Motorola Nexus 6 does not support video out of its microUSB port with any adapter/protocol.

You could cast video from the phone to a Google Chromecast ($35 MSRP) HDMI dongle, and then purchase an active HDMI female to VGA male cable/adapter to connect the Chromecast to your monitor - but note that the Chromecast and phone would need to be on the same WiFi network, and there is slight latency in wireless casting that you wouldn't get with a video cable.

Comment: how sure that Nexus 6 does not support video out of its microUSB?

Comment: I'm sure. The last Nexus phone to support video out was the Nexus 5. You won't find any official documentation for the N6 mentioning video out capability - just forum threads of people who cannot get it working: https://www.reddit.com/r/nexus6/comments/2oaw4g/video_out_on_nexus_6/

Comment: seems that I will have to use [hdmi coupler](http://www.amazon.in/CLASSYTEK-Coupler-Changer-Extender-Connector/dp/B001VO4MOY)(need to buy), [HDMI-to-VGA adapter](https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-Active-Adapter-Micro-USB/dp/B00879DM56)(which I already have) and a chromecast (which is also I have already) to get it done???

Comment: @Mahesha999 Sounds like that's what you'll need.